# Up voting show an error when revote an unrefresh page

Tags: bug, voting

First I just want to say it's just a little and not important bug.
But when I upvote a question (I think it's the same thing with down vote) the upvote button appear in orange in the counter increment.

For example:
[image: Up button appear in orange and counter increment]

But if I click on a link (or navigate to another page on the same tab) after this and then I come back with the back button of my browser (chrome), the button and the counter appear to the start state :
[image: Button and counter reappear to the start state]

So I think it's maybe normal because Google Chrome (and maybe the other, don't test) take the page from the cache, but if I revote a little bit later (it's append to my because I forget that I voted up), I get an error that say me that my vote is locked :
[image: Error message is show and the state is update]

If I don't wait 47 minutes and revote directly, it just show me the same thing that the picture one, so it don't remove my vote, so I think it just missing a verification before showing this error message.

Comment: [Looks like caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) Clicking again tries to undo your vote, which can succeed (in the first few minutes) or fail (afterwards, unless the post is edited).

Comment: If your vote *isn't* locked, your vote is changed from an upvote to an upvote, so no error is shown. Using the back button is not supported; all sorts of things break in that case.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi except that this is browser caching. Using the back button and expecting the page to behave normally is an unfair expectation.

Comment: The thing that is weird is that if the vote isn't lock, it don't change anything, don't undo my vote or vote twice, so there is a verification but not for the error message.
But if the back button is not supported like say @Martijn Pieters it's normal

Comment: If you refresh the page, it will show that you upvoted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens quite often to me for some reason. I re-discover some old browser tab, and think "I've forgotten to vote"..

I'm fine with the lock-in, but **a simple check that prevents voting from stale pages** would be nice. All I think that takes is a parameter being passed to the server as part of the voting request, which reflects the arrow state on the page. On the server side that could then be compared to the server-side "has already voted" state. If the two are different, just send back a notice saying "refresh the page".

Comment: Thank's for having understood this, it's exactly what I would like to say and the solution proposed would be great

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug related to caching. It is not a bug.

Learn about this protection here: [Why do votes get locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80763).

Comment: Yes I know this but in this case (picture 2), there seem like I haven't vote, and it's catch if my vote is not lock (no problem, no undo vote) but not if my vote is lock (error message)